# need to display the required field of the student table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to C# I have sending the list of students to the model. But I also need only the specified list to display when I enter the value in routing.

this is my controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Project1.Models;

namespace Project1.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var studentList = new List<Student>
            { 
                new Student() { StudentId = 1, Studentname = "aa", Age = 18 } ,
                new Student() { StudentId = 2, Studentname = "bbb",  Age = 21 }           
            };

            return View(studentList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You should start by reading tutorials, or, more preferably books about C# first (because you said you were a beginner) and then about ASP.NET MVC. Just hopping into random topics without proper understanding is absolutely pointless in the world of programming.

Comment: i need to access specified list example if i give ..../1 in url i need to display only studentid1 only

Comment: Then you should add an `int id` parameter to `Index` and then filter the collection as `return View(studentList.Where(s => s.StudentId == id));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an `int id` parameter to the `Index` action and then filter the collection as

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var studentList = new List<Student>
    { 
        new Student() { StudentId = 1, Studentname = "aa", Age = 18 } ,
        new Student() { StudentId = 2, Studentname = "bbb",  Age = 21 }
    };

    return View(studentList.Where(s => s.StudentId == id));
}
```

The name of the parameter does matter, I wrote `id` because this is set up in the routing config by default.

Answer (score 0):

You've default index method. You need overloading.

Your base method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var studentList = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student() { StudentId = 1, Studentname = "aa", Age = 18 },
        new Student() { StudentId = 2, Studentname = "bbb",  Age = 21 }
    };
    return View(studentList);
}
```

And its overloading

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var studentList = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student() { StudentId = 1, Studentname = "aa", Age = 18 },
        new Student() { StudentId = 2, Studentname = "bbb",  Age = 21 }
    };
    return View(studentList.Where(filter => filter.StudentId == id));
}
```

Your class's final situation will be like:

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var studentList = new List<Student>{ new Student() { StudentId = 1, Studentname = "aa", Age = 18 } , new Student() { StudentId = 2, Studentname = "bbb",  Age = 21 } };
        return View(studentList);
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var studentList = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student() { StudentId = 1, Studentname = "aa", Age = 18 },
            new Student() { StudentId = 2, Studentname = "bbb",  Age = 21 }
        };
        return View(studentList.Where(filter => filter.StudentId == id));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should point out the routing-related issue here, namely that the default parameter name is `id`, so nothing will be bound to `filter` unless he does the proper config.

Comment: You're right. I've edited it. Old habits. Normally I do not use default parameter in my own projects.